# How do i find the first song in my playlist? (singly-linked list)

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores a playlist.  It is defined very simply with just three columns:

- setID - 16 digit hex that references a row in my playlists table
- songID - 16 digit hex that references a row in my songs table
- nextID - 16 digit hex that contains the songID of the next entry

This works well for adding new songs to the end of the list, and for rearranging songs in general, but is there a way for me to query this list for the id of the first element in the list?  aka the one that no nextID links to?

At the moment I'm thinking of storing the first songID in the playlists table, but if possible, I'd like to avoid muddling them like that.

Comment: is an option to change your model? or you have to stick with it?

Comment: it is an option to change to an indexed model, and it may be what I have to do, but I wanted to see if the possibility existed to make a linked list work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor data structure for a SQL database.  The relational model doesn't handle explicit linked lists very well.

Instead you should have a table that has columns such as:

- setID
- songNumber
- songID

And store them in a single table.

The answer to your question, though, is:

```
select *
from playlist
where nextID is null;
```

However, I would call this the *last* one, not the first one.

EDIT:

You can get the first as:

```
select *
from playlist pl
where not exists (select 1 from playlist pl2 where pl2.nextid = pl.id and pl2.setId = pl.setId);
```

Comment: that actually *is* the last one.  I need to identify the first one.  Not the one that *has* no nextID, but the one that *no nextID references*.  Song number is a pain because I don't need to explicitly know number and I only reorder by moving one song at a time.  In a numbered setup I need to renumber a potentially large number of rows to move one song  in a linked list, i only update two rows.